# Aligning JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

[image: This is the output I want pretty much]I have to align a button on my program to the exact middle, the current code I have runs it but displays the button as large as the program, I am wanting a center button that is a specific size, here is what I tried

```
/**
 * Created by Timk9 on 11/04/2016.
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Test extends JFrame {

{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setSize(600, 600);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
//Button does not appear until I resize the program?
    JButton b1 = new JButton("Click here");
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    p.add(b1);
    window.add(p);

        }

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Test();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you add the button to window before you set the layout manager?

Comment: And why are you using an instance initializer block and not a constructor?

Comment: Use borderLayout and position it in the center.

Comment: @dijam: which will fill almost the entire GUI with button. Not good. Timothy, for further more detailed help, please post a link to an image showing what you're trying to achieve. Again, the link should be to an image, not a web page, and then we can help you load the actual image into your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have just added my new code and my current output even though there are still issues. Also could you point out which part is an instance initializer block, I thought I was using a constructor but I am new to creating my own shell to allow visual programs to run.

Comment: @FredK little mistake

Comment: The "standard" Layout Managers are remarkably unfriendly about this. Mig Layout or Spring Layout will typically be the better choice.

Comment: @Compass, how is the GridBagLayout unfriendly? Why would you want do download a 3rd party class or use the complicated SpringLayout when GridBagLayout provides a simple solution?

Comment: @camickr Is the GridBagLayout a default layout? It's been a while since Swing for me. If it is a default layout, then I would like to amend to say the "usual standard" layouts such as Grid, Static, and so on, are unfriendly for doing something like that.

Comment: @Compass, The GridBagLayout is one of the standard core layout managers like BorderLayout, FlowLayout, GridLayout, BoxLayout etc. If does not make a layout manager unfriendly if it doesn't do everthing. Layout managers are not designed to do everything. You need to understand how each layout manager is designed to be used and then use the appropriate layout manager or combination of layout managers. Don't try to force a layout manager to do something it wasn't designed to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

You create a panel with a GridBagLayout which is a good layout manager to use to center the component.

```
p.add(b1);
```

But then you add the button to the panel without using any contraints.

The code should be:

```
p.add(b1, c);
```

> //Button does not appear until I resize the program?

All components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. The `setVisible(...)` statement should be the last statement of the constructor.

> Also could you point out which part is an instance initializer block, I thought I was using a constructor

See the `FrameDemo` example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a better way to structure your code so you follow Swing conventions. Start with the working code and make the changes to add your panel containing the button, instead of using the JLabel. Note you no longer need to use the getContentPane() method, you can just add the panel directly to the frame.

Answer (score 1):

It is the `LayoutManager` that defines how components are layed out where and how big. `GridLayout` which you are using e. g. divides the available space in equal grid fields and makes the components completely fill this space which is why your button is as big as your application. See here for more info about LayoutManagers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Btw. your code is not compilable: `new JButton("he"),JButton.ALIGN_CENTER)`